# How to use ternary operator in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Can some one tell me what im do wong
Im try to use ternary operator in v-slot scope

Here is my code

```
<template :v-slot="category.children.length ? `activator` : `default`">
    <v-list-item-avatar>
       <v-img :src="`/uploads/image/category/` + category.image"></v-img>
    </v-list-item-avatar>
    <v-list-item-content>
       <v-list-item-title v-text="category.name"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</template>
```

If anyone knows a solution to this problem, I will be very grateful

Comment: nothing wrong with your ternary , what errors are you getting does both `v-slot="activator"` and `v-slot="default"` work? you may need a `v-if="category.children"` somewhere if the model is not predefined as an array

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Unless you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Im just guessing, you get `property of undefined` error?

Comment: In this situation whem im using ternary operator the page not a render
But when im using simple v-if v-else everything ok

Answer (score 3):

In order to use dynamic slot names, you need to use this syntax as specified [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names):

```html
<base-layout>
  <template v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]>
    ...
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

For example you can add a computed property like so:

```js
computed: {
  dynamicSlotName() {
    return this.category.children.length ? "activator" : "default";
  }
}
```